# popup notifier using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, popupwindow

in my application, I have a page that contains a form (named form1.aspx), I want that when the user validates this form, a popup window appears indicating that everything is fine.
I used popup notifier, but the problem that nothing is displayed knowing that I unlocked the use of popups in my browser

Here is my code

```
 PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
        popup.TitleText = "Result";
        popup.ContentText = "aaaaa";
        popup.Popup();
```

Comment: ASP.NET Web Forms is not the same as Windows Forms. You can't just launch a popup from server side code and instantly expect something to happen on the browser. Where did you get this PopupNotifier class? What namespace is it in?

Comment: I used Tulpep.NotificationWindow from nuget package

Comment: That library is for Windows Forms. Windows Forms is for creating a UI on the machine where the code is running. And where does that code run in ASP.NET? On the server. Not on the client. Don't use any Windows Forms code in your ASP.NET library. You'll need to learn the web way of doing things, HTML, CSS, and JS.

Comment: Something like toastr is a good shout for user notifications: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Comment: Yes as @SteveJ use toastr or similar on the web side.

Comment: Yes, client side.  [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) is nice for those popup dialogs.